# Trying to wrap a py function with tf.py_func but have an error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use tf.py_func to wrap a python function. But it gives me error. My code is:

```
def label_energy(energy):
    return scipy.ndimage.measurements.label(energy)
labels_gt, _ = tf.py_func(label_energy, [gt_single_energy], tf.float32)
```

And I have error:

```
"Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not "
TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not 
enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

I can wrap other functions, for example

```
def gaussianblur(energy, tu, x):
    return cv2.GaussianBlur(energy, tu, x)
```

But not this `label_energy()`

Comment: If your function returns more than one element, you need to specify the Tout for each in your py_func